# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH

Tags: java, encryption

I use aes-256-cbc for data encrypt/decrypt.

When decrypt data with php code i'm not getting an error.

Php code like this:

```
$key = 'd7df7d66bc110ba2e03a3a647ecd8c3f';
$iv = '73e8c03a24b4bb1e';
$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$encrypted_text = "K0JOVFQreEQ4TlRjWGwyNXBhejRtQWVWU2doVkRsUjkvaEhQamlRdWRIWWpQQ0dVWmNpNTJXR3hhbXdWbDN4WGJpcGZTblpHRVpyeGpDY2lLc3o4cGJEeHdwdmZDTUlxalRyeDdVYlB4SmJtVUhEQkVSN3VZSklWb2h0dlZkYmY=";


$output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
```

output:

```
{"Sayfa":"b2pneVd4bUcQT09","TelNo":"905373603204","Sifre":"9cbf8a4dcb8e30682b927f352d6559a0"}
```

But when decrypt data with android ( java ) code i getting an error like this:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH
```

Java code :

```
String key = "d7df7d66bc110ba2e03a3a647ecd8c3f";
String iv = "73e8c03a24b4bb1e";
String encryptedText = "K0JOVFQreEQ4TlRjWGwyNXBhejRtQWVWU2doVkRsUjkvaEhQamlRdWRIWWpQQ0dVWmNpNTJXR3hhbXdWbDN4WGJpcGZTblpHRVpyeGpDY2lLc3o4cGJEeHdwdmZDTUlxalRyeDdVYlB4SmJtVUhEQkVSN3VZSklWb2h0dlZkYmY=";

AESUtil.decrypt(encryptedText,key,iv);

public String decrypt(String encryptedText, String key, String iv) {
        byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedText,Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        byte[] ivBytes = getIvBytes(iv);
        return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, ivBytes), "UTF-8");
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        }
 private byte[] getIvBytes(String iv) {
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] parameterKeyBytes= iv.getBytes(characterEncoding);
        System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }

    private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key){
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[32];
        byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes(characterEncoding);
        System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }
```

where is the error in java code?

Comment: how can i solve this error

Comment: You're missing the `getKeyBytes` and `getIvBytes` methods.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: update my question. thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Android, and on regular Java (Oracle JavaSE 8) after replacing that Base64 decoder with the Oracle one I don't get that error, but I *do* get `BadPaddingException` because your data is actually *double* base64 encoded. In your PHP this works because you decode explicitly once, then `openssl_decrypt` with options=0 does the second decode.

In Java if I base64-decode the data *twice* (and use key and IV directly as bytes, as PHP did, even though they *look* like they should be hex-decoded) it does decrypt successfully and as expected. According to the doc on developer.android.com I *think* Android's `Base64.DEFAULT` is the same as Oracle's default, but I can't verify that myself.